# Use a selector value in a selector without losing synchronicity

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to get the result of one selector to be used in an other one, all being synchronous.
I have my method searchBirthTown :

```
searchBirthTowns({ debounce, scheduler } = { debounce: 500, scheduler: asyncScheduler }) {
        // This selector gives me the birthDate
        this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.getBirthDate), first()).subscribe(x => this.date = x);

        // This one returns me the city, ideally with the birthDate 
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(fromStore.selectBirthFormAutocompleteField),
            filter(field => field === 'birthCommune'),
            switchMap(_ =>
                this.store.pipe(
                    select(fromStore.selectBirthFormAutocompleteData),
                    map(x => x.seized),
                    filter(x => !!x),
                    debounceTime(debounce, scheduler),
                    distinctUntilChanged(),
                    switchMap(city => this.nomenclatureService.listBirthTowns({ label: city, birthDate: ? }))
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

I have tried to use combineLatest to merge them both but without success.
Any idea ?

EDIT :

I solved it by gibing `this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.getBirthDate), first())` as a parameter for birthDate and then treating the Observalbe in listBirthTowns().

It might not be the best solution though.

Comment: It didn't work how? Where you put `comnineLatest`?

Comment: @martin I found a workaround (I made an edit in the original post). It might be not be the best but it works